# Using Twig to declare template and pass in additional content between the parent template's block

Tags: twig

I have the following code that I repeat multiple times in my layout:

```
<div id="hi">
    <div class="howAreYou">
        <p class="fineTYForAsking">
            <!-- additional HTML logic goes here -->
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I put in the above html into a single Twig template, and then use that template and put in my additional specific html in the `<!-- additional HTML logic goes here -->` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just define blocks and embed the template where ever you want

*partial.twig.html*

```html
<div id="{{ id | default('hi') }}">
    <div class="howAreYou">
        <p class="fineTYForAsking">
             {% block content %}
             {% endblock %}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*template.twig.html*

```html
{% embed "partial.html.twig" with { 'id' : 'foo' } %}
    {% block content %}
         Lorem Ipsum
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

---

You could also use an embed in a for-loop. Variables known inside the loop, are also know in the embedded file, e.g.

*item.html.twig*

```html
<div{% if item.id|default %} id="{{ item.id }}"{% endif %}>
    <div class="howAreYou">
        <p class="fineTYForAsking">
             {% block title %}
                 {% if item.title is defined %}
                 <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
                 {% endif %}
             {% endblock %}
             {% block content %}
                 {% if item.content is defined %}
                 <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
                 {% endif %}             
             {% endblock %}            
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*template.html.twig*

```html
{% for item in items %}
    {% embed "item.twig" %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/nirm94)